AWS SAM: Resource handler returned message: "Function creation failed because the function already exists" when deploying using SAM
I have a current lambda function called "appNotificationService" and I want to try experimenting deploying using SAM from my local machine.
Currently I have the following SAM template.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An AWS Serverless Application Model template describing your function.
Resources:
  appNotificationService:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: appNotificationService
      CodeUri: .
      Description: Returns app status and notification messages for the Platform
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs20.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      EphemeralStorage:
        Size: 512
      EventInvokeConfig:
        MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 21600
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 2
      FunctionUrlConfig:
        AuthType: NONE
        InvokeMode: BUFFERED
        Cors:
          AllowCredentials: false
          AllowHeaders:
            - '*'
          AllowMethods:
            - GET
          AllowOrigins:
            - '*'
          ExposeHeaders: ["*"]
          MaxAge: 60
      PackageType: Zip
      Policies:
        - Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - logs:CreateLogGroup
              Resource: arn:aws:logs:eu-west-2:123456:*
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
              Resource:
                - >-
                  arn:aws:logs:eu-west-2:123456:log-group:/aws/lambda/appNotificationService:*
      SnapStart:
        ApplyOn: None
      RuntimeManagementConfig:
        UpdateRuntimeOn: Auto



when I deploy this I get the following error:
"Resource handler returned message: "Function creation failed because the function already exists"
my aim is to be able to make code changes etc and then deploy to the same function to update it.
Any help would be apprecitated.
Thanks

Does this answer your question? How to update existing lambda function using AWS SAM
